# sql query for for merging two query of same row

Tags: mysql, sql, foxpro, dbase

```
SELECT (SSTA*2)as gst, sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo FROM DIS GROUP BY SSTA WHERE FLG="P"

SELECT (SSTA*2)as gst, sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo FROM DIS GROUP BY SSTA WHERE FLG="G"
```

how to make make one query so to run concurrently.

```
P                G
Gst| gstamo|     gst| gstamo|
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but have you considered using OR operator or a UNION query?

Comment: Post an example of the result. But I guess you need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 4):

You can express it as using single `where` clause  :

```
SELECT SSTA*2 as gst, 
       sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo 
FROM DIS 
WHERE FLG in ('P', 'G')
GROUP BY SSTA;
```

For separate *columns* you can use *condition* aggregation :

```
SELECT SSTA*2 as gst, 
       sum(case when FLG = 'P' then SSTAAMO else 0 end) as Pgstamo,
       sum(case when FLG = 'G' then SSTAAMO else 0 end) as Ggstamo  
FROM DIS 
WHERE FLG in ('P', 'G')
GROUP BY SSTA;
```

Comment: Actually I want two gst row and two gstamo column of same column naming ssta and sstaamo simultaneously

Comment: @jainpiyush484. . . For separate column then you can do separate aggregation. Check edited part.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just asking in general, use a [union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) between the two queries.

```
SELECT (SSTA*2)as gst, sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo FROM DIS GROUP BY SSTA WHERE FLG="P"
UNION
SELECT (SSTA*2)as gst, sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo FROM DIS GROUP BY SSTA WHERE FLG="G"
```

If you're asking specifically for the code you posted, just change your WHERE to:

```
WHERE FLG="P" OR FLG="G"
```

Comment: Actually I want two gst row and  two gstamo column of same column naming ssta and sstaamo simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SSTA*2) as gst, sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo 
  FROM DIS 
  WHERE INLIST(FLG,"P","G") 
  GROUP BY SSTA
```

Comment: THIS QUERY WILL COMBINE FLG "G" AND "P" RESULTS

Comment: Please show us some original data and the result you want from that data. It's too hard to read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what SQL Syntax you are using.

Remember that your SQL Syntax needs to match the database from which you are getting your data.  The Foxpro SQL Syntax is slightly non-standard and different from the MySQL SQL Syntax.

Your posting tags:   **mysql sql foxpro dbase**
include Foxpro, so can I assume that you are using the FP SQL Syntax to query Foxpro data tables?

> I want two gst row

If I understand what you are wanting, it seems as though you want the gst for "P" results in one row and the gst for "G" results in a separate row.

If you are getting your data from a Foxpro data table, then you might consider something like the following:

```
SELECT (SSTA*2)as gst, IIF(Flg = "P","P","G") as SortFlg, sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo FROM DIS WHERE FLG $ "P,G" GROUP BY 1,2
```

Introducing the added field SORTFLG and making it (the #2 field) part of the GROUP BY statement, will force the results for "P" and "G" into separate result rows.  You can always remove that extra field later if desired.

If you are getting your data from another database with SQL Syntax that does not support the IIF() syntax, you can use the CASE syntax to create your new SORTFLG.

**EDIT**: Why I didn't think of it before, I have no idea.  Regardless, you don't need the IIF() syntax at all.   You can still introduce the new, 2nd field   **SORTFLG**  but instead of using the IIF() command, you can use the FLG field alone, but make sure that you include in into your GROUP BY line so that your result will have a separate "P" record and "G" record.

```
SELECT (SSTA*2)as gst, Flg as SortFlg, sum(SSTAAMO) as gstamo FROM DIS WHERE FLG $ "P,G" GROUP BY 1,2
```

Good Luck

Comment: ITS WORKING BUT CAN WE HAVE IN DIFFERENT COLUMN FOR "P" AND "G"  FLG's

Comment: You can have the Flg ("P" & "G") field anywhere and name it anything ("Flg" or something else with the "AS" clause) as long as it continues to be included in the GROUP BY clause.